# Email issue in hudson/Jenkins

Tags: email, hudson, jenkins

Some time I get failed notification email in jenkins even though build is passed? How to reslove this issue, I am using jenkins 1.430, using email ext 2.14

Thanks

Comment: What does the email say?

Comment: Do you have any reports enabled? If some files were not created from the build or not found in the specified directory it can fail the Job and send a mail about that! Check the console output of the Job and it should explain a bit more about the problem that caused the failed notification mail...

Comment: It send as if the build failed in real scenario, actually build is running in the console :) , enable email send if it is failed :) strange behavior..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has issue in the plugin. Had to downgrade it for now.